# Moving the absolute value to the power

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it generally true that $|e^z| \leq e^{|z|}$ for $z \in \mathbb C$? I thought of using it in a certain problem but I fail to see if that is even true in all cases.

Answer (score 4):

Consider that

$$\left|e^z \right| = \left| \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!} \right| \le \sum_{n \ge 0} \left| \frac{z^n}{n!} \right| = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{|z|^n}{n!} = e^{|z|}$$

by using the triangle inequality and standard algebraic properties of these functions. You should be able to fill in the more formal details yourself.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before (easily found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Ce%5Ez%7C%20%5Cleq%20e%5E%7B%7Cz%7C%7D%24)).